# Check if container contains specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have container, that i got using `$(this).parent()`. And i want to check if this container contains element with tag `form`. Is there any way to do this with jquery?

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: use: `$(this).parent().find('form').length`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var container = $(this).parent();
var hasForm = container.find('form').length > 0;
```

Comment: note: you can also perform this directly, by "just" concatenating these two steps. +1 for additional insight

Comment: @André Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if ($(this).parent().find('form').length)
   alert('its here')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) function

```
if($this.parent().has('form').length > 0);
```